# Upload files through cloud functions Admin SDK - Broken Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have been trying to upload files (mostly images) to firebase storage through firebase cloud function (onRequest method). I had to upload files from its *base64* form. With the below code, i was able to achieve it, yet the file seems to be broken after upload.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
const database = admin.database();
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const safetyLogsAPI = express();
safetyLogsAPI.use(cors({ origin: true }));

safetyLogsAPI.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { 
            attachments,
            projectId
        } = req.body;
        const safetyKey = database.ref('safetyLogs')
          .child(projectId)
          .push().key;
        if(attachments && Array.isArray(attachments)) {
          if (attachments.length > 0) {
            for (let index = 0; index < attachments.length; index++) {
              const base64Obj = attachments[index];
              const { content, fileName, contentType } = base64Obj;
              const stream = require('stream');
              const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
              bufferStream.end(Buffer.from(content, 'base64'));
              const fullPath = `SafetyIncidentLog/Images/${projectId}/${safetyKey}/${fileName}`;
              const file = bucket.file(fullPath);
              const metadata = {
                projectId,
                safetyLogId: safetyKey,
                createdTimestamp: Date.now(),
                systemGenerated: 'false',
                fileType: 'Image',
                fileName,
                path: fullPath
              };
              bufferStream.pipe(file.createWriteStream({
                metadata: {
                  contentType,
                  metadata
                },
                public: true,
                validation: "md5"
              }))
                .on('error', (err) => {
                  console.log('Error Occured');
                  console.log(err);
                })
                .on('finish', () => {
                  console.log('File Upload Successfull');
                });
            }
          }
        }
        return res.status(200).send({
            code: 200,
            message: 'Success'
        });
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).send({
            code:500,
            message: 'Internal Server Error',
            error: error.message
        });
    }
});

module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(safetyLogsAPI);
```

I have tried this approach with both the prefix part `data:image/png;base64` present and eliminated. In both ways i see broken image. So where have I gone wrong. Is there a better way to make it?

Thanks in advance.

Also, is the approach i try to do so is a recommended way?. For use cases like, profile picture upload, and conversation image attachments, is this way recommended, or the a direct upload from client is recommended?

Comment: Can you try this, he mentioned its working for him https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488959/upload-base64-encoded-jpeg-to-firebase-storage-admin-sdk

Answer (score 2):

With Cloud Functions HTTP triggers, the request is terminated and the function is shut down as soon as you send a respond to the client.  Any asynchronous work that isn't finished might never finish.

What I'm seeing in your code is that you send a response before the upload is complete.  I can see that your call to `res.status(200).send()` happens immediately after you start the upload.  Instead, your code should wait to send the response until after it completes, perhaps using `on('finish')` and `on('error')`.